Aplicacion publicada, no funciona en diferentes navegadores
vengo con la siguiente consulta:
He creado una aplicación la cual la tengo publicada en mi servidor de railway.
La misma aplicación, esta creada con React js, tailwind y next ui.
El problema que estoy teniendo es el siguiente:
Tengo aproximadamente 10 clientes que apuntan a la url, por ej cliente.miurl.com,
y me pasa que a mi siempre me funciona, y tengo a un cliente que no le funciona bien, que apreta botones y no hace nada, los textos estan en minusculas (todos los textos estan con mayusculas al principio).
Y lo raro es que no puedo reproducirlo porque a mi me funciona bien, pero a mi cliente no, y estamos apuntando a la misma url (ya que esta publicado, repito).
Principalmente no funciona en google chrome (en incognito SI funciona), limpiamos cache y tampoco funciona.
En mozilla SI funciona.
En safari SI funciona.
Me pasa tambien que tengo un datepicker de mui, y a los dias martes y miercoles les pone metrometro, y el dia 16 le escribe "dieciseis"
A alguien le sucedió algo similar alguna vez?

por todo lo que decis, tiene roto su chrome... lo reinstalo???
